# Custom permalink leads to index page

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I have a custom post type named `patch` and custom permalink structure:

`www.site.ru/patch/%version_id%`

I managed to replace `%version_id` with actual version code with this code:

```
add_action('init', 'patch_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('post_type_link', 'patch_permalinks', 10, 3);

function patch_rewrite_rules() {

    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%version_id%', '([^/]+)', 'version_id=');

    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('patch', '/patch/%version_id%', false);

}

function patch_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename) {

    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if($post->post_type != 'patch' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
        return $permalink;

    $version_id = get_field('version_id', $post_id);

    $permalink = str_replace('%version_id%', $version_id, $permalink);

    return $permalink;

}
```

So now I have links with proper URL, for example:

`www.site.ru/patch/1.8.1`

But all of them lead to site main page!

How to make this link lead to specific patch (`version_id` is an unique meta property)?